# bootClasspath property unknown

Tags: gluon-mobile

When I create a new Gluon Mobile project,  I am able to compile the Android and Desktop versions fine. However when I select the ios target it fails with:

Could not set unknown property 'bootClasspath' for object of type org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.

Can anyone help me out?  Thanks David

Comment: Have you checked the [Getting started guide](https://docs.gluonhq.com/getting-started/#introduction)'? You should edit your question and post more details about what you have done so far, your build.gradle file, your OS, Java version ...

Comment: Jose:  thanks, the getting started guide was very useful.  Now I am getting an IncorrectArchitecture error.  I will create a new question with details about that.